# Mail queue keep growing

Tags: email, postfix, inode

My server keeps running short on inodes due the mail queue getting crazy.
First, I assumed I had `postfix` not configured properly, so I switched it off.
But, it happened again, last time I did it I had :

```
# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 375122 messages
```

While I could put a cron to run this every morning, that does not seem to be the optimal solution.

What could be the cause of such a behaviour? How can I prevent this too happen?

Comment: "What could be the cause of such a behaviour?" - have you checked the logs?

Comment: yes, I get a lot of :   `Jan 28 10:15:14 localhost postfix/sendmail[31977]: fatal: www-data(33): No recipient addresses found in message header`

Comment: `www-data` sounds like your web server may be involved. What kind of mails collect in your mail queue? Post the output of `mailq | tail`.

Comment: Found here something close to my problem : http://goo.gl/0TX8PP - but it does not indicate a clear solution

Comment: mailq | tail is giving stuff like  `54625451BC     1368 Tue Jan 28 10:49:46  www-data@ip-172-31-16-112.eu-west-1.compute.internal
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.176.20]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         artnotabene@mail.ru`

Comment: and no, I don't know any artnotabene@mail.ru :)

Comment: Is it possible that there some kind of PHP site running on your server that has been hacked and that is now sending spam?